# How to get meta value in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How can I get meta value from HTML head in Angular2?

For example I have the HMTL of my project and I would like to get the meta name "userId".

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SampleProject</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="userId" value="12345">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('meta["userId"]').getAttribute('value')
```

There is no special support for this from Angular2.

If you try to avoid direct DOM access, you can read this before you start Angular2 and pass it to Angular using DI.

```
var userId =     document.querySelector('meta["userId"]').getAttribute('value');

// @Injectable(),  @Component(), or @Directive()
class ServiceOrComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('userId') private userId:string) {}
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: 'userId', useValue: userId]}
  ....
})
export class AppModule()
```

Instead of the `'userId'` string you also can use an [`OpaqueToken`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html)

Comment: Thank you @GunterZochbauer . The `document.querySelector...` should be `document.querySelector('meta[name="userId"]').getAttribute('value')`. I will check `OpaqueToken`

Comment: AFAIK the inner quotes are not necessary if there are no spaces and the value doesn't start with a number (perhaps other characters as well). Thanks for the feedback anyway. I updated the answer.